# FCM HTTP Request returns message_id but no message is received on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notifications on my server to my Android device. I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for sending the notifications. I can send notifications via the Firebase Console and I receive the message on my phone. However, I'm trying to send a message via my server, which isn't working yet.

I'm getting the following response when I execute the code below:

> "{\"message_id\":58934758934758936346437}"

When we look into the documentation of Firebase right here [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), we can see that receiving a message_id implies that the message has been send succesfully. I'm not receiving it on my phone though.

I did subscribe the app to the right topic.

I'm running the following code:

```
private void test(String topic) {
    try {
        //Setup request
        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection hc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        hc.setDoOutput(true);
        hc.setDoInput(true);

        //Set request params
        String message = "{\"to\": \"/topics/" + topic + "\"}";

        hc.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        hc.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=SECRET");

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(hc.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(message);
        dos.close();

        //Get Response  
        InputStream is = hc.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();

        label.setText("RESPONSE: " + response.toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        label.setText("Er ging iets mis");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're payload ***does not contain any message***.

```
String message = "{\"to\": \"/topics/" + topic + "\"}";
```

It only contains the recipient (`to`), but there is no actual message. Either send a `notification` or `data` message payload. Something like this:

```
String message = "{\"to\": \"/topics/" + topic + "\",
    \"notification\" : {
        \"title\" : \"sample title\",
        \"body\" : \"sample body\"
    }
}";
```

See the available parameters for `notification` and `data` [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and note that those two message payloads are handled differently. See the [Receiving Messages in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) docs for more details.